# Python PANDAS: pivot_table count for multiple columns on same level?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot-table

I have a pandas dataframe with the following general layout (dummy data):

```
trans_id,prod_id,loc,ind_1 or ind_2,ind_any
1,thing_1,place_1,ind_1,ind_any
2,thing_3,place_2,ind_2,ind_any
3,thing_2,place_1,ind_1,ind_any
4,thing_1,place_1,ind_1,ind_any
5,thing_2,place_3,ind_2,ind_any
```

I can create a pivot_table with the following layout easily enough:

```
prod_id ->

ind_1 ind_2

(n)(%)(n)(%)

loc 
|
V
```

However, I am trying to include an additional count for "ind_any" on the same level as "ind_1 or ind_2" like this:

```
prod_id ->

ind_1 ind_2 ind_any

(n)(%)(n)(%)(n)

loc 
|
V
```

Unfortunately, I cannot just concatenate results done separately together, since they need to be ordered properly for final output.  Any tips or tricks would be most appreciated!

**Edit:**

Here is the desired output format I would expect with the dummy data:

```
       thing_1             thing_2             thing_3
       ind_1 ind_2 ind_any ind_1 ind_2 ind_any ind_1 ind_2 ind_any
       (n)(%)(n)(%)(n)     (n)(%)(n)(%)(n)     (n)(%)(n)(%)(n)        
place_1
place_2
place_3
```

I will adapt my actual code to the dummy data and provide when I get the chance

Comment: show us your code , or you expected output

Comment: @Wen I have added the expected output and will add the adapted code for the dummy data when I get the chance.  Thanks

Comment: why you can not concat , Your index is loc, that is exactly concat problem

Comment: I have to have that exact ordering "ind_1, ind_2, ind_any", unfortunately. The results are too huge to manually fix the output.

Comment: Entry with 'place_1', 'thing1 and 'ind1' is duplicate. How would you expect it to be resolved? And if I understand correctly, you want trans_id to be the value in your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

raw = ['trans_id', 'prod_id', 'loc', 'ind_1 or ind_2', 'ind_any', 
       '1', 'thing_1', 'place_1', 'ind_1', 'ind_any', 
       '2', 'thing_3', 'place_2', 'ind_2', 'ind_any', 
       '3', 'thing_2', 'place_1', 'ind_1', 'ind_any', 
       '4', 'thing_1', 'place_1', 'ind_1', 'ind_any', 
       '5', 'thing_2', 'place_3', 'ind_2', 'ind_any']
raw = np.asarray(raw).reshape(6,5)
df = pd.DataFrame(raw[1:, :], columns=[raw[0,:]])

df2 = pd.concat([df.loc[:,['trans_id', 'prod_id', 'loc', 'ind_1 or ind_2']].rename(columns={'ind_1 or ind_2':'ind'}),
                df.loc[:,['trans_id', 'prod_id', 'loc', 'ind_any']].rename(columns={'ind_any':'ind'})])

df3 = (df2.loc[:,['prod_id', 'loc', 'ind','trans_id']]
     .groupby(['loc', 'prod_id', 'ind'])
     .count()
     .unstack(level=[1,2])
     .fillna(0)
     .sort_index(axis=1))
print df3
```

**Output:**

```
        trans_id                                              
prod_id  thing_1         thing_2               thing_3        
ind        ind_1 ind_any   ind_1 ind_2 ind_any   ind_2 ind_any
loc                                                           
place_1      2.0     2.0     1.0   0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
place_2      0.0     0.0     0.0   0.0     0.0     1.0     1.0
place_3      0.0     0.0     0.0   1.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
```

Comment: Would there be a simple way to add percentage as well?